# Curl And Potential

Tags: rotations, vector-fields, cross-product, scalar-fields, curl

Every vector field which has a potential, therefore it can be expressed as the gradient of a certain potential, doesn't have any curl.

Thus : $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{v} = 0$, where $\vec{v}$ is the vector field in question.

The question is:

Is the other way around also true? does every vector field without any curl always have a potential ?

Comment: Depends on the topology of the domain of the definition of the field. If the domain is simply connected (no holes), it works...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field#Irrotational_vector_fields